# CORS-aided cross-origin-XHR

Tags: ajax, browser, cors

Modern browsers support `CORS` handily. If `CORS-aided cross-origin-XHR` is sent to `CORS-ignorant` site, the XHR succeeds in no question.

Does it expose more vulnerability in this regard? How to strictly enforce `Same Origin Policy` on today's browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how preflight requests work in CORS. The CORS preflight request protects servers from unauthorized requests by first asking the server whether it is ok to make the cross-origin request. If the server says "yes", the browser continues with the request. Otherwise the request fails.

Note that there are certain types of requests that don't need preflight requests. However, these requests were already possible even before CORS. For example, a simple GET request does not need a preflight, but a GET can already be made with a `script` tag.

You can learn more about CORS and the preflight here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/